# JavaBeans Component java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list

i am trying to do a javaBeans component but it give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at probarcomponente.ProbarComponente.main(ProbarComponente.java:37)
Java Result: 1
```

The component:

```
public class Componente implements Serializable {
    private List<Persona> lista;


    public Componente() {
    }


    public class Personas {

        List<Persona> lista = new LinkedList<Persona>();

    }

    public List <Persona> Mostrar() {

        try {
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.128/mibase", "asis", "titanic24");
            java.sql.Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from dades_pers";
            ResultSet result = comando.executeQuery(sql);

            while (result.next()) {

                String nif = result.getString(1);
                String nom = result.getString(2);
                String cognoms = result.getString(3);
                String tel = result.getString(4);

            Personas p = new Personas();

            // Inserción en la lista 
            p.lista.add(new Persona(nif,nom,cognoms,tel)); 


            }  

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al mostrar datos");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        return lista ;

    }

}
```

I have another class "Persona" with her attributes,constructor ,getters and setters.

```
public class Persona {
   private String nif ;
   private String nom;
   private String cognoms;
   private String telf;

    public Persona(String nif, String nom, String cognoms, String telf) {
        this.nif = nif;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.cognoms = cognoms;
        this.telf = telf;
    }

    public String getNif() {
        return nif;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public String getCognoms() {
        return cognoms;
    }

    public String getTelf() {
        return telf;
    }

    public void setNif(String nif) {
        this.nif = nif;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public void setCognoms(String cognoms) {
        this.cognoms = cognoms;
    }

    public void setTelf(String telf) {
        this.telf = telf;
    }




}
```

and finally i create another project to test the component:

```
public class ProbarComponente {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Componente comp = new Componente();

        List<Persona> lista = new LinkedList<Persona>();
        lista= comp.Mostrar();
        System.out.print("Tamaño de la lista es"+lista.size());

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code and it works fine. Instead of SQL database i have used Oracle, you can change

that accordingly.

```
public class Componente implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            List<Persona> lista = new LinkedList<Persona>();

            public Componente() {
            }


    public List <Persona> Mostrar() {

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "oracle");
            Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from dades_pers";
            ResultSet result = comando.executeQuery(sql);

            while (result.next()) {

                String nif = result.getString(1);
                String nom = result.getString(2);
                String cognoms = result.getString(3);
                String tel = result.getString(4);

                lista.add(new Persona(nif,nom,cognoms,tel));
            }  

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al mostrar datos");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        return lista ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with JDBC too ,the key was declare up the  List<Persona> lista = new LinkedList<Persona>()  .Thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score 0):

The method `comp.Mostrar()` is returning `null`. The `lista` property in the `Componente` class is never set. The `comp.Mostrar()` method is adding `Persona` instances to the `lista` variable in the `Personas` class. I am not sure what the requirement is, but you probably need  to return `p.lista` from the `comp.Mostrar()` method.